# Is kernel a process?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, kernel

according to wikipedia

> > In computing, a process is an instance of a computer program that is being executed. It contains the program code and its current activity. Depending on the operating system (OS), a process may be made up of multiple threads of execution that execute instructions concurrently.

according to this definition a kernel should be a process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a software development question.

Answer (score 2):

A kernel is bigger than a process. It creates and manages processes. A kernel is the base of an operating System to make it possible to work with processes.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel is a comprehensive/complex process, that handles all other tasks(threads) in both kernel and user space

Kernel's PID is 0, and that triggers all other processes(Kernel/User), directly(children) and indirectly(child handling other subsequent children).

Kernel runs the scheduler, which is the core part of task/process management.

To see the kernel Processes that are spawned by kernel

> ps -caefL | grep -v grep | grep "\[\|PPID" | grep root

to see the user space processes,

> ps -caefL | grep -v grep | grep -v "\["

You will not be able to see the line of 0th PID, which is the kernel(the driving force)

Good to say that ***kernel is, "device driver for the CPU"***